# Can not get grandchild state to work with UI Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using Angular 1.6.2 and UI Router. I am still trying to learn the concepts correctly, but have come to a road block.

I have a parent state called `app` using `MainController`, and a bunch of child states. However I now want to go one level deeper by making grandchild states.

The following codes leaves me with a blank page when loading `www.example.com/manage-users/edit/1` thus not loading the grandparent state.

However it does work if I make `app` a parent of `edit-users` (the one I want to make a third level deep), but thats not really the correct way of going about it. Because after this I need to use the parent states for other reasons.

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <base href="/">
    // loading JS/CSS etc
</head>
<body ng-app="sampleApp">
<div class="container">
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**parent.html**

```
<div ng-controller="MainController as data">
    // more html
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

**manage-users.html**

```
<div class="col-sm-12" ng-controller="UserController as data">
    // more html 
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

**manage-users-edit.html (only works when I make the parent state 'app' instead of 'manage-users'**

```
<div>Hello World! This is the Edit HTML Page</div>
```

**app.js setting up states**

```
$stateProvider
    .state('app', {
        templateUrl: 'views/parent.html',
        controller: 'MainController as data'
    })
    .state('manage-users', {
        parent: 'app',
        url: '/manage-users',
        templateUrl: 'views/manage-users.html',
        controller: 'MainController as main'
    })
    .state('edit-users', {
        parent: 'manage-users',
        url: '/manage-users/edit/:id',
        templateUrl: 'views/manage-users-edit.html',
        controller: 'MainController as main'
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <base href="/">
        // loading JS/CSS etc
    </head>
    <body ng-app="sampleApp">
        <div class="container" ui-view="container"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**parent.html**

```
<div ng-controller="MainController as data">
    // more html
    <div ui-view="parent"></div>
</div>
```

**manage-users.html**

```
<div class="col-sm-12" ng-controller="UserController as data">
    // more html 
    <div ui-view="manageusers"></div>
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
$stateProvider
    .state('app', {
       views:{
           'container': { 
                templateUrl: 'views/parent.html',
                controller: 'MainController as data'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('app.manage-users', {
        url: '/manage-users',
        views:{
             'parent':{
                   templateUrl: 'views/manage-users.html',
                   controller: 'MainController as main'
              }
        }
    })
    .state('app.manage-users.edit-users', {
        url: '/edit/:id',
        views:{
             'manageusers':{
                   templateUrl: 'views/manage-users-edit.html',
                   controller: 'MainController as main'
              }
        }
    });
```

You should always navigate to the child of your hierarchy. In this case, `$state.go('app.manage-users.edit-users')`

**EDIT:**

Your URL property in state config is wrong. To hit what you expect, you should enter `http://exapmle.com/#/manage-users/edit/1`.

I have updated the config, so extra manage-users from the URL is removed. Give it a shot.

Comment: Thanks for this, it did help me learn a bit more and positioning my `ui-view`s etc and I have actually applied your views strategy above. But despite all that once I tell `edit-users` to have a parent that isnt `app`it fails.

Comment: your edit spotted the issue! After that its now working, thanks very much!